# Alphabetical list in bootstrap

Tags: css, list, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I currently have my alphabetical list in a table and I would like to make it into a list instead using Bootstrap. I am looking at the documentation and can't find anything that I like. What is the best way to do this ?  I was thinking something like this...

Have A, B, C etc on the left side and list group items on the right

Should I even use this list or something else that Bootstrap offers ? Thanks!

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In HTML you can use `<ol>` with `type` attribute, like this:

```
<ol type="1|a|A|i|I">
```

Indicates the numbering type:

- `a` indicates lowercase letters,
- `A` indicates uppercase letters,
- `i` indicates lowercase Roman numerals,
- `I` indicates uppercase Roman numerals,
- `1` indicates numbers (default).

Example:

```html
<ol type="1">
  <li>foo
  <li>bar
  <li>baz
</ol>

<ol type="a">
  <li>foo
  <li>bar
  <li>baz
</ol>

<ol type="A">
  <li>foo
  <li>bar
  <li>baz
</ol>

<ol type="i">
  <li>foo
  <li>bar
  <li>baz
</ol>

<ol type="I">
  <li>foo
  <li>bar
  <li>baz
</ol>
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol#attr-type

Or with CSS with `list-style-type` attribute with values:

- `lower-alpha` or `lower-latin`: lowercase ASCII letters
- `upper-alpha` or `upper-latin`: uppercase ASCII letters
- `lower-greek`: lowercase greek letters
- `upper-greek`: uppercase greek letters

---

**Note:** `list-style-type` supports severals values, see examples with all types (more details in [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=list-style-type)):

```js
var values = [
  'disc', 'circle', 'square', 'decimal', 'cjk-decimal', 'decimal-leading-zero', 'lower-roman', 'upper-roman', 'lower-greek',
  'lower-alpha, lower-latin', 'upper-alpha, upper-latin', 'arabic-indic', 'armenian', 'bengali', 'cambodian', 'cjk-earthly-branch',
  'cjk-heavenly-stem', 'cjk-ideographic', 'devanagari', 'ethiopic-numeric', 'georgian', 'gujarati', 'gurmukhi', 'hebrew',
  'hiragana', 'hiragana-iroha', 'japanese-formal', 'japanese-informal', 'kannada', 'katakana', 'katakana-iroha', 'khmer',
  'korean-hangul-formal', 'korean-hanja-formal', 'korean-hanja-informal', 'lao', 'lower-armenian', 'malayalam', 'mongolian',
  'myanmar', 'oriya', 'persian', 'simp-chinese-formal', 'simp-chinese-informal', 'tamil', 'telugu', 'thai', 'tibetan',
  'trad-chinese-formal', 'trad-chinese-informal', 'upper-armenian', 'disclosure-open', 'disclosure-closed', '-moz-ethiopic-halehame',
  '-moz-ethiopic-halehame-am', 'ethiopic-halehame-ti-er', 'ethiopic-halehame-ti-et', 'hangul', 'hangul-consonant', 'urdu',
  '-moz-ethiopic-halehame-ti-er', '-moz-ethiopic-halehame-ti-et', '-moz-hangul', '-moz-hangul-consonant', '-moz-urdu'
];

var example = document.querySelector("#example");
var opts = document.querySelector("#opts");

opts.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  console.log("change", e.target);
  example.style.listStyleType = e.target.value;
});

for (var i = 0, j = values.length; i < j; i++) {
  var value = values[i];

  var opt = document.createElement("label");
  
  var radio = document.createElement("input");
  radio.name = "list-type";
  radio.type = "radio";
  radio.value = value;
  
  var text = document.createTextNode(value);

  opt.appendChild(radio);
  opt.appendChild(text);

  opts.appendChild(opt);
}
```

```css
#opts > label {
   float: left;
   width: 32%;
   height: 24px;
   margin: .5%;
   border-radius: .3em;
}

#opts > label:hover {
   background: #fcfcfc;
}
```

```html
<ol id="example">
   <li>foo</li>
   <li>bar</li>
   <li>baz</li>
   <li>foo</li>
   <li>bar</li>
   <li>baz</li>
</ol>

<div id="opts"></div>
```

Comment: You can also set this is with CSS: `list-style-type: lower-alpha;`, for example

Comment: The answer isn't just could, you __should__ do it like that according to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol (ps. w3schools is a bad source.)

Comment: @rwacarter I added your info in answer, Thanks!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento according to MDN the page you linked to actually does have wrong information :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use the `list-style-type` css property for this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type